# Date difference in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
AssignmentID    UserFrom    UserTo  GroupFrom   GroupTo CreatedOn
201410            NULL      4327    103         103      2014/11/11 09:24.7
201549           NULL      4327     103         103      2014/11/11 09:32.4
201549           NULL      4327     103         103      2014/11/11 09:38.4
 201673         NULL       4328    103          103      2014/12/11 09:56.1
 201673         NULL       4328    103          103      2014/12/11 10:55.1
 201673         NULL       4328    103          103      2014/12/11 10:59.1
```

I want to have datedifference in minutes vertically group by userto
in following way.Please give me suggestion to produce following output.

```
 userto   minutes
 4327      8  
 4327      6
 4328     55 
 4328      4
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: When you're using SQL2012 you can use `LAG` and `LEAD`, otherwise try to solve it with `ROW_NUMBER` and a self-join. That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sqlserver 2008, you could use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Note this will not work well with duplicated CreatedOn within the same UserTo:

```
SELECT 
  t1.UserTo, 
  DateDiff(minute, 0, t1.CreatedOn - t2.previousCreatedOn) minutes
FROM yourtable t1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) previousCreatedOn
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE 
    t1.UserTo = UserTo
    AND CreatedOn < t1.CreatedOn
  HAVING 
    MAX(CreatedOn) is not null
) t2
```

If you are using sqlserver 2012 it is easy using [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LAG_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    userto, 
    datediff(minute, 0, createdon -lag(createdon) over 
      (partition by userto order by createdon)) minutes
  FROM yourtable
)
SELECT userto, minutes
FROM CTE
WHERE minutes is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()`:

```
select userto, diff
from (select userto,
             datediff(minute, lag(createdon) over (partition by userto order by createdon), createdon) as diff
      from table t
     ) t
where diff is not null;
```

Comment: Because you unaccepted this answer, I assume you are not using one of the more recent versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can join the table to itself, with join conditions that only allow each row to join (match) the very next row for the same user in chronological sequence

```
Select a.userTo, 
   datediff(minute, a.createdOn, b.CreatedON) minutes
from table a
    join table b 
        on b.userto = a.Userto
           and b.createdon =
                (Select Min(createdOn)
                  From table 
                  Where userTo = a.UserTo
                  and createdOn > a.createdOn)
```